# Mathf.Hermite not available in Mathf

Tags: unity, c#

I see [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Mathfx#C.23_-_Mathfx.cs) that Hermite should be function in the class Mathf.

However, when I try to use it, the compiler tells me that Mathf doesn't contain a definition for Hermite.

This is an example:

```
    float fNewDistance = Mathf.Hermite(_initialDistance, _GoalDistance, fTime);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you using it? Can you share a minimal code sample?

Comment: @doppelgreener I have added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not available. What you're looking at is `Mathfx`, an extension you can manually add. Create a new script called Mathfx.cs and paste the code in there.

Then call using Mathfx.Hermite